# What does fragmented memory look like?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, java-me, memory-fragmentation

I have a mobile application that is suffering from slow-down over time. My hunch, (In part fed by [this article](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/site/global/techsupport/tipstrickscode/java/p_avoidingmemoryfragment.jsp),) is that this is due to fragmentation of memory slowing the app down, but I'm not sure. Here's a pretty graph of the app's memory use over time:

[fraggle rock http://kupio.com/image-dump/fragmented.png](http://kupio.com/image-dump/fragmented.png)

The 4 peaks on the graph are 4 executions of the exact same task on the app. I start the task, it allocates a bunch of memory, it sits for a bit (The flat line on top) and then I stop the task. At that point it calls System.gc(); and the memory gets cleaned up.

As can be seen, each of the 4 runs of the exact same task take longer to execute. The low-points in the graph all return to the same level so there do not seem to be any memory leaks between task runs.

What I want to know is, is memory fragmentation a feasible explanation or should I look elsewhere first, bearing in mind that I've already done a lot of looking? The low-points on the graph are relatively low so my assumption is that in this state the memory would not be very fragmented since there can't be a lot of small memory holes to be causing problems.

I don't know how the j2me memory allocator works though, so I really don't know. Can anyone advise? Has anyone else had problems with this and recognises the memory profile of the app?

Comment: The normal Java VM compacts its heap as part of its garbage collection duties (removing any fragmentation) - not sure about J2ME though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a little bit of time, you could test your theory by re-using the memory by using Memory Pool techniques: each run of the task uses the 'same' chunks of memory by getting them from the pool and returning them at release time.

If you're still seeing the degrading performance after doing this investigation, it's not memory fragmentation causing the problem. Let us all know your results and we can help troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 0):

Memory fragmentation would account for it... what is not clear is whether the Apps use of memory is causing paging? this would also slow things up.... and could cause the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

It the problem really is memory fragmentation, there is not much you can do about it.

But before you give up in despair, try running your app with a execution profiler to see if it is spending a lot of time executing in an unexpected place.  It is possible that the slow down is actually due to a problem in your algorithms, and nothing to do with memory fragmentation.  As people have already said, J2ME garbage collectors should not suffer from fragmentation issues.

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking at garbage collection statistics.  You should have a lot more on the last run than the first, if your theory is to hold.  Another thought might be that something else eats your memory so your application has less.

In other words, profiler time :)

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you running this on? I have some experience with Windows CE5 (or Windows Mobile) devices. CE5's operating system level memory architecture is quite broken and will fail soon for memory intensive applications. Your graph does not have any scales, but every process only gets 32MB of address space on CE5. The VM and shared libraries will take their fair share of that as well, leaving you with quite little left.
The only way around this is to re-use the memory you allocated instead of giving it back to the collector and re-allocating later. This is, of course, much more low-level programming than you would usually want to do in Java, but on this platform you might be out of luck.